# Weird Varnish 503 error - what does this mean?

Tags: varnish

My online whiteboard application has been working previously, but for whatever reason, it no longer works. Now it shows a 503 Varnish cache error as seen here: http://grab.by/eFHG

Do you happen to know where I should start to look to try to resolve this issue?

Thanks!
Donny

Comment: Did you find out the reason why your app was throwing 503?

Comment: I've been getting this `Error 503 Backend fetch failed` error frequently on my Cloudways server. I will probably try this soon: https://community.cloudways.com/t/many-error-503-backend-fetch-failed/343/4

Comment: Please update the address since that address doesn't anymore lead to the error page. Using a link to a screenshot image would be much better now. Fastly CDN failure generated a large number of varnish error screenshots e.g. in Twitter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This error means that Varnish had no response (even not an HTTP error) from the backend within the timeout limit.

You can troubleshoot that in many ways :

- On the backend : do you see requests from Varnish in your webserver
  log ?
- On Varnish server : Run varnishlog and check the request process. You should have events in this order : RxRequest > TxRequest > RxResponse > TxResponse. Your problem is between TxRequest (request sent to backend) and RxResponse (response received from backend).
- On your Varnish server try connecting on the backend using telnet (telnet  ). Does it connect ? If it does, try sending a request (e.g. "GET / "). Do you receive a response ?

Probable causes could be : firewall/selinux blocking between varnish & backend, bad varnish or backend web server config (are backend address & port sync ?), webserver stopped, ...

Comment: I found this occurred after a full stack restart. After restarting varnish on it's own after the stack it was fine

Answer (score 6):

You could always check your `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` (CentOS).

```
backend default {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "80";
}
```

Make sure the `.host` value is your server IP Address, and change the port to `8080`, and adjust your port setting in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and make sure Apache listen to `8080`.

**EDIT**

It could also mean web server (Apache) have *wrong*/default settings.

- Check the virtual host ports, the values might be `80`, they should be
  `8080`.
- Check Listen directive and ServerName, they must have `8080`
  port.
- Make sure you do `sudo systemctl enable varnish`.
- And for the final touch, do `sudo reboot` (cache programs are bugging me in the development state).

Comment: It also worth noting - as I experienced this first hand. The cache folder may not be within your domain setup altogether.

We have 2 domains setup on the same server. When the hosting team setup the 2nd domain (they insist they setup the profile - I then install Magento) they left some setting to point the cache to a folder on the 1st domain.

When I cleared out the 1st domain - the 2nd site went down with Varnish errors - it seemed impossible to be connected so a new extension which had been installed on the 2nd site took the blame for a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to reach this page today, I got shown the error page instead with following contents:

```
Error 503 Service Unavailable
Service Unavailable

Guru Mediation:
Details: cache-hel6832-HEL 1623148717 170212118
```

So it seems StackOverflow is also using a CDN that was failing today, and the failure was impacting huge number of services at the same time. In these kind of situations, we might be at the mercy of external CDN provider. Today showed us that sometimes the only thing that you can do, is to wait for the others to solve it for you.
[Luckily these kind of outages are shortlived](https://theconversation.com/fastly-global-internet-outage-why-did-so-many-sites-go-down-and-what-is-a-cdn-anyway-162371).

Suitable long term strategy is to use several CDN services instead of single.